# network coverage for mobile phones - europe

Tags: data, telecom

I am looking for GIS data with the network coverage (mobile phones). Something like the layer shown in the [cell mapper website](http://www.cellmapper.net/) where I can select different countries and all the providers to export a GIS layer with the towers heatmap would be great.

Although a nice raster with coverage given by all the providers would be perfect, I am guessing that maybe something like this is not public, I can also manage to work with presence/absence of network coverage by administrative regions in Europe.

Any help is appreciated, it is the first time I am trying to find & use this type of data, so I might have failed to find any obvious websites, or what I am looking for is not possible to obtain.

[image]

Comment: UK (EE 'Orange') http://coverage.ee.co.uk/ee/coveragechecker.html it is a slow site - 4G, 3G and 2G coverage and warning: http://coverage.ee.co.uk/ee/etc/ee-coverage.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out http://www.opencellid.org/ this is an open source project offering open data. There might be some working involved in turn the data into "GIS" data but could be a good place to start.

You can download the "raw" data at http://dump.opencellid.org/ - you're probably looking for the "cells" data, which is given as CSV (easily imported into any GIS format):
id,lat,lon,mcc,mnc,lac,cellid,range,nbSamples,created_at,updated_at

Answer (score 0):

opencellid is the best option which is available for free. Operators have the coverage maps but they are not available for the public. Some companies provide measurements similar to the crowd sourced measurements which is not free.